# Finding JDK after installing Java via PPA repository

Tags: java-8

Where do I find the java JDK after installing it via PPA repository in Linux Mint? I followed [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
```

Running `java` and `javac` work, showing version `java version "1.8.0_101"`. Running `whereis` shows both binaries at `/usr/bin/` folder. Running `printenv JAVA_HOME` shows me the `/usr/` directory (I set it by hand, I assumed that was the proper folder).

When I run NetBeans, though, it cant find the `jdkhome`. I've changed `netbeans.conf` to have `netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/"`, and I also tried running with the `--jdkhome /usr/` option, but to no avail.

What directory should be the JDK home after installing Java the way I have? Or how do I find it?

Comment: Some form of this question has been asked countless times.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/84/compile-and-run-your-first-java-program/4421/installing-java-development-kit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout `ls -l /usr/bin/java` to see where does the symbolic link point to.

Or you can also try:

```
update-alternatives --all | grep java
```

Comment: `update-alternatives --all | grep java` showed me the correct directory, `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/`